# Is there any option in config of OpsCenter to automatically start repair service?

Tags: cassandra, opscenter

I made an OpsCenter and attach the cluster to it. I don't want to "click" manually to start repair service, instead, I want repair service to start by default (config?) Any help?

Comment: I can't give you exact steps on how to do this, but the answer revolves around the directory /var/lib/opscenter/repair_service. When you enable repair by clicking the button, 8 files are generated for each cluster in this directory. 4 of them are for incremental repairs, 4 are for sub-range repairs. Of these files, 2 of them are SQLite database files, 4 are data, and 2 are JSON files with status info. Figure out how to do this automatically and you'll be able to enable repair without clicking the button once a cluster is added.

Comment: @JimWartnick these are internal details that are subject to change. REST API is safer way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [OpsCenter's REST API](https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.7/api/docs/) to trigger repair service, particularly, you need this repair service API, that is just posting the time to completion to the `/{cluster_id}/services/repair` endpoint. For example, if your time to complete is 9 days, the command could be:

```sh
curl -X POST -d '{"time_to_completion": 777600}' \
  http://<OpsC_hostname>:8888/<cluster_name>/services/repair
```

Please note, that if repair service is already enabled, you need to disable it with:

```sh
curl -X DELETE http://<OpsC_hostname>:8888/<cluster_name>/services/repair
```

and then enable with `POST` again.

Comment: Additionally, I'll add that once repair service is activated, it remains active even across opscenter restarts. So you only need to activate it once, per cluster.